# Ça n'en vaut pas la peine

Tags: expressions, expressions-idiomatiques

I understood that this sentence means, it's not worth the trouble, but, Why is there 'en' between ne and vaut? What does it signify? Is it a pronoun?

In which other connotations can "en" be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This "en" means "de le faire" (The "doing" in "It's not worth doing"). The sentence without "en" would be :

> ça ne vaut pas la peine de le faire

"En" can be used when when you have a verb using the preposition "de", for example :

> J'ai mangé de la tarte.

If the pie was already mentioned before, you could just use "en" instead :

> Mr X : As-tu mangé de la tarte ?
>
> Mr Y : Oui, j'en ai mangé.